# Aligning components in a TableRow layout

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to create a header that is a little similar to the facebook android app. The header should have a header title in the middle with a button on each side.

I have the header title but my code below does not show either button. I'm not sure if this info helps but the TableRow layout for this header is taking up a lot of height space. It used to wrap the until the title's height until I attempted adding buttons.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#008000" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/menuButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/HeaderTextView"
            android:text="Button" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/HeaderTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/header"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/infoButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/HeaderTextView"
            android:text="Button" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me. For what ever reason, the `android:layout_weight="1"` makes it work.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/menuButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Button" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/HeaderTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="This is the title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#FFFfff"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/infoButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".MainActivity" >


<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/menuButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Button" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/HeaderTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/menuButton"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/infoButton"
    android:text="headersfasfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="italic" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/infoButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! This helped but at the moment, the buttons are sticking close to the title. I would like the buttons closer to the left and right edges of the screen. Which command should I use for that?